# How to use messages in itself?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eval

*message.properties*

```
my.hello=hello
my.hello-world=${my.hello} world!  (it doesn't work)
```

Is there a way to use eval expression in messages.properties like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't find a build-in implementation. I write a library [`Nest-Message-Spring-Boot`](https://github.com/XDean/nest-message-spring-boot)

#### Use nest message expression

```
hello.guy=Hello {0}!
hello.world=$(hello.guy,world)
```

`hello.world` will be `Hello World!`

#### Use argument placeholder

```
hello.two=Hello {0} and {1}!
hello.owt=$(hello.two,$1,$0)
```

`hello.world` with `{a, b}` will be `Hello b and a!`

#### Complex expression with escaper and quoter

```
book.name=<{0}>
book.price=\${0,number,#.#}
book.promote=Come to buy {0} with $(book.price,$1)
java.promote=Hello guys! $(book.promote,$(book.name,java)"(2nd edition)",{0})
```

`java.promote` with `{123}` will be 
`Hello guys! Come to buy <java>(2nd edition) with $123`

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible if you extends `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` and in the `loadProperties` method you should do some parsing and conversion for those properties in which their value contains placeholder prefix and suffix